# How to print out Apify requestQueue.getInfo() at run time?

Tags: output, apify

[The docs on requestQueue.getInfo()](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/request-queue#requestqueuegetinfo).

### Code

```
function printRequestQueue(requestQueue){
    let { totalRequestCount, handledRequestCount, pendingRequestCount } = 
    requestQueue.getInfo()
        .then(()=> {
            console.log('\nRequest Queue:\n   total:', this); 
            console.log('\nRequest Queue:\n   total:', totalRequestCount); 
            console.log('   handled:', handledRequestCount, '\n   pending:', pendingRequestCount);  
          })
        .catch( (error) => console.log(error)); 
}
```

When run in the runtime environment `Apify.main(async () => { ... }`, it returns `undefined`:

```
Request Queue:
   total: undefined
   handled: undefined
   pending: undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be returning the contents of the response back from the operation promise and so the variables are indeed uninitialized at the time of logging them. Operation itself should be returning this result and you can confirm so by logging the result of the promise - e.g. `.then(response) => {console.log(response)}`:
https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/request-queue-info

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Vasek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745212/vasek-tobey-vlcek). I post below **2 solutions**:

### Solution 1

```
async function printRequestQueue (requestQueue){
  var { totalRequestCount, handledRequestCount, pendingRequestCount } = await 
  requestQueue.getInfo();
  console.log(`Request Queue info:` );
  console.log(' - handled :', handledRequestCount);
  console.log(' - pending :', pendingRequestCount);
  console.log(' - total:'  , totalRequestCount); 
}
```

---

### Solution 2

```
function printRequestQueue (requestQueue){ 
  requestQueue.getInfo().then((response)=> { 
    console.log('total:', response.totalRequestCount); 
    console.log('handled:', response.handledRequestCount, '\n   pending:', 
     response.pendingRequestCount);  
    console.log('\nFull response:\n', response); })
 .catch( (error) => console.log(error)); 
}
```

One may read **full explanation** in [here](https://webscraping.pro/how-print-requestqueue-info-apify/).